# Weighting with restrictions, but no clear objective function?

Tags: optimization, problem-solving

Here is the problem:

I have 40 shares in an index and I want to weight them based on their market value, define the known value as $x_i$

In the traditional way, the weight of each share is calculated as:

$w_i = x_i / \sum^M_{j=1} x_j $ for $M = 40$

However, now I want to apply the following restrictions:

- $w^{k}_s <= 0.05$
- $\sum^{N_k}_{s=1} w^{k}_s <= 0.10$ for all  $k = 1...K$
- $\sum^{K}_{k=1} \sum^{N_k}_{s=1} w^{k}_s = 1$

Moreover, each share belongs to one sector $k$, the sum of the weights of the shares within each of these sectors should be less or equal to 0.10.
In addition, the weight of each individual share $i$ should be less or equal than 0.05.
Summing up all the weight $w^{k}_s$ should add up to 1.

My questions are:

- How to solve this?
- What is the solution?
- Is there an objective function and what is it?

Many many thanks!

Comment: There may be more than one solution (or there may be no solution). In particular there is the question of when the constraints bite, given the choice would you prefer to have individual shares close to their "true weight" or to have sectors close to their "true weight"? Either way, one approach would be to run this and give preliminary weights, then constrain those over the bounds, and revise those with unconstrained preliminary weights, then rinse and repeat until you have a solution or cannot improve the situation.

Comment: What do you want to optimize in your problem ?

Comment: @Peter That is also part of the question? Is there an objective function and how could we define it?

Comment: @JohnAndrews You have to have a objective function. It may be risk minimization or sharpe ratio maximization.